# Is the diagonal in the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: measure-theory

> Is the diagonal $\Delta_\mathbb{R}:=\{(x,x):x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ in the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, where $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ is the power set of $\mathbb{R}$?

I know that $\Delta_{X}\notin\mathcal{P}(X)\otimes\mathcal{P}(X)$ if $|X|=2^{|\mathbb{R}|}$. (A proof can be found as an exercise in the first chapter of 
*Analysis III* by H. Amann and J. Escher.) It seems that whether $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R})=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ relies on set theoretic axioms like the continuum hypothesis. I wonder whether the diagonal is in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: is there supposed to be a tensor product?

Comment: @PinkPanther The tensor $\otimes$ denotes the product $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\Delta _{\mathbb R}=F^{-1}(\{0\})\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)\otimes \mathcal B(\mathbb R)\subset \mathcal P(\mathbb R)\otimes \mathcal P(\mathbb R),$$ where $F(x,y)=y-x$.

Answer (score 2):

$\{(x,y): x>y\}=\cup_{r \in \mathbb q} \{(x,y): x>r>y\}=\cup_{r \in \mathbb q} (r,\infty) \times (-\infty ,r)$. Hence $\{(x,y): x>y\}$ belongs to the  product sigma algebra? A similar argument shows that $\{(x,y): x>y\}$ belongs to the  product sigma algebra. It should now be clear that the diagonal is also in the  product sigma algebra.